# Four different sprinkles in a collection merge into one sprinkle in a geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, collections, clipping

I started the new doughnut tutorial from BlednerGuru, and I am on part 7 (long sprinkles). When placing the sprinkles in one collection and putting it in the geometry nodes, they merge into one sprinkle only. There are no variants and I can see the sprinkles clipping in the one that's on the icing. [image]

[image]